# WCF Client Certificate set in App.Config

Tags: wcf-client, x509certificate, client-certificates

I'm working with a vendor who exposes a Java web service.  I've created a WCF client to consume their service, but I'm having some problems with the client cert.  The vendor is claiming that our requests do not contain the client cert and are rejecting our requests.  I'm not 100% convinced this is on our side, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything from the cert config.

**App.Config**

```xml
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NewBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="[CLIENT_CERT_NAME]" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
           logEntireMessage="true"
           logMalformedMessages="false"
           logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
           logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
           maxMessagesToLog="3000"
           maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="VendServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://[SERVICE_URL]/Vend/VendService"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VendServiceBinding"
          contract="VendService" name="VendService" behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Client.cs**

```cs
VendServiceClient client = new VendServiceClient("VendService");
createMemberResponse response = new createMemberResponse();
createMember member = new createMember();

// Check Certificate Just Before Executing
string certCheck = Environment.NewLine + "Check Certificate Just Before Executing - ClientCredentials Name: " + client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate.GetNameInfo(
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509NameType.SimpleName
    , false) + Environment.NewLine;

member = GetCreateMember(reader, siteConfig, recordID);
response = client.createMember(member);
returnStatus = response.VendHeader.ReturnStatus;
DetailedErrorMessage = response.VendBody.Vend.DetailedErrorMessage;
```

During execution I can check "certCheck" and see the name of the certificate, so I know I'm picking it up out of the cert store.  I'm also assuming this means that the certificate should be attached when I make the request to "client.createMember()".  The error I get back is via some custom validation against the cert the vendor is performing ... maybe the problem is with their validation???

when I installed the cert (.pfx) I was required to enter a password, do I need this password to use the cert as well?  I haven't added it anywhere in the config or in code.

Any ideas on how I can confirm that my request contains the client cert?

[UPDATE]
I was finally able to run Fiddler, I was expecting to see some certificate details in the header, but this is what I have.  Does this mean I'm not sending the certificate?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <ActivityId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics" CorrelationId="10afd012-1130-42ea-aaa8-281c9fab723a">395f129c-fd59-48b1-a19d-387bbffe1465</ActivityId>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <createMember xmlns="http://[SERVICE_URL]/Vend/VendService">
         <createMember xmlns="">
            <VendHeader>
```

[UPDATE]
I have fiddler working, looking at the "Tunnel to" line I can see the certificate of the server, but nothing from my own client certificate.  Still confused, it should be here right?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 10:37:08.575
Connection: close

Encrypted HTTPS traffic flows through this CONNECT tunnel. HTTPS Decryption is enabled in Fiddler, so decrypted sessions running in this tunnel will be shown in the Web Sessions list.

Secure Protocol: Tls
Cipher: Rc4 128bits
Hash Algorithm: Md5 128bits
Key Exchange: RsaKeyX 2048bits

== Server Certificate ==========
```

Comment: Have you tried using a http proxy (fiddler) and checking the request?

Comment: I'm trying to get our sys admins to let me install it on my dev box, they've locked our boxes down pretty tight.  Pretty much a fiddler newbie to boot.